# How to update and upsert multiple documents in MongoDB using C# Drivers

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I am using MongoDB 2, and I want to update multiple documents and upsert a value like `processed:true` 
into the collection. But MongoDB c# api only allows us to either Update Multiple Records or Upsert a single record.

How to solve this problem using the C# api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# mongodb driver 2.0 - How to upsert in a bulk operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687470/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-2-0-how-to-upsert-in-a-bulk-operation)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After `Mongo 2.6` you can do Bulk [Updates/Upserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/). Example below does bulk update using `c#` driver.

```
MongoCollection<foo> collection = database.GetCollection<foo>(collectionName);
      var bulk = collection.InitializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
      foreach (FooDoc fooDoc in fooDocsList)
      {
        var update = new UpdateDocument { {fooDoc.ToBsonDocument() } };
        bulk.Find(Query.EQ("_id", fooDoc.Id)).Upsert().UpdateOne(update);
      }
      BulkWriteResult bwr =  bulk.Execute();
```

Comment: Our Development team uses -MongoDB 3.0.0  and -MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714. The MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714 complains about InitializeUnorderedBulkOperation() being undefined.

Comment: while this is the accepted answer, its outdated. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687470/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-2-0-how-to-upsert-in-a-bulk-operation/35688613#35688613

Comment: The comment above is incorrect and is for upserting documents -- which is not the same a updating individual fields in multiple documents.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot do it in one statement.

You have two options

1) loop over all the objects and do upserts

2) figure out which objects have to get updated and which have to be inserted then do a batch insert and a multi update

Answer (score 11):

For those using version 2.0 of the [MongoDB.Driver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongodb.driver), you can make use of the BulkWriteAsync method.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
// our example list
List<Products> products = GetProductsFromSomewhere();  

var collection = YourDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("products"); 

// initialise write model to hold list of our upsert tasks
var models = new WriteModel<BsonDocument>[products.Count];

// use ReplaceOneModel with property IsUpsert set to true to upsert whole documents
for (var i = 0; i < products.Count; i++){
    var bsonDoc = products[i].ToBsonDocument();
    models[i] = new ReplaceOneModel<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("aw_product_id", products[i].aw_product_id), bsonDoc) { IsUpsert = true };
};

await collection.BulkWriteAsync(models);
```

Comment: That helped me. Thanks a lot. In my case I get an IEnumerable as items to be upserted. `BulkWriteAsync` takes an IEnumerable, so I modified it to something like this: `var models = items.Select(item => new ReplaceOneModel<T>(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<T>(doc => doc.Id == item.Id), item) { IsUpsert = true });`

Answer (score 2):

Try first removing all items to be inserted from the collection, and then calling insert:

```
        var search = [];
        arrayToInsert.forEach(function(v, k) {
            search.push(v.hash); // my unique key is hash. you could use _id or whatever
        })
        collection.remove({
            'hash' : {
                $in : search
            }
        }, function(e, docs) {

            collection.insert(arrayToInsert, function(e, docs) {
                if (e) {
                    console.log("data failed to update ", e);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("data updated ");
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: The one problem with this is that clients reading the collection may see missing objects during the operation. If your clients can tolerate that, then this seems a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

A prettier and more robust approach:

```cs
public interface IProjection
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; }
}
```

```cs
public async Task UpsertManyAsync<TProjection>(IEnumerable<TProjection> replacements, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    where TProjection : IProjection
{
    var requests = replacements.Select(replacement => new ReplaceOneModel<TProjection>(
        filter: new ExpressionFilterDefinition<TProjection>(projection => projection.Id == replacement.Id),
        replacement: replacement) { IsUpsert = true });

    await _context
        .GetCollection<TProjection>()
        .BulkWriteAsync(
            requests: requests,
            options: new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false },
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: really cool. where did you come up with this? just to help others: this is for upsert single data item:  await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == data.Id, data, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true }).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 1):

UpdateFlags is an enum in the C# driver that will let you specify both at once. Just like any other flags enum, you do this by bit "or"ing.

```
var flags = UpdateFlags.Upsert | UpdateFlags.Multi;
```

You can read the docs on enums here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) paying special attention to the section on Enumeration Types as Bit Flags

Answer (score 1):

Working with mongoose@5.9.9 - try initializeUnorderedBulkOp():

```
export const InfoFunc = (Infos: Infos[]) => {

  const bulk = InfoResult.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  Infos.forEach((info: Infos) => bulk.find({ "Id": info.Id}).upsert().updateOne(info));
  bulk.execute();
}
```