# UpdateFlags.Upsert and UpdateFlags.Multi together in Update()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, upsert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update and upsert mulitple documents in MongoDB using C# Drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934768/how-to-update-and-upsert-mulitple-documents-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-drivers)

This may be a silly question. Actually I am confused with the syntax. An update from shell has this format:
`db.collection.update(query,update,options)`

where options are for upsert and multi flags. I can write something like this in the shell and it works:
`db.users.update({"Gender":"female"},{$set:{"Hubby_name":1}},false,true)})`
to mean that find all females ( since multi is true) and in their documents, add the key "Hubby name". If no female is found, don't do anything (since upsert is false).

Now how do I specify this (both the flags) in C# code? I am able to add only one flag in the Update method. The next parameter prompted by intellisence is SafeMode which I am not interested in. Also, what is the default behavior when I don't give any options at all?

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you could so much as sacrifice 2 points of your reputation, you could spend 2 minutes to answer my question:-) If I was not clear, let me try again: I am asking how to specify both the upsert and multi flags in Update method of C#. I am not sure if the question is meaningless in some sense because the equivalent query does exist on the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateFlags is an enum in the C# driver that will let you specify both at once.  Just like any other flags enum, you do this by bit "or"ing.

```
var flags = UpdateFlags.Upsert | UpdateFlags.Multi;
```

You can read the docs on enums here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) paying special attention to the section on Enumeration Types as Bit Flags

Comment: Thanks..this is exactly what I wanted to know :-)