# Trying to do a bulk upsert with Mongoose. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that holds documents that contains three fields: first_name, last_name, and age. I'm trying to figure out what query in Mongoose I can use to do a bulk upsert. My app is occasionally receiving a new array of objects with those same three fields. I want the query to check if the first AND last name already exist within a document, and if they do - update the age if it's different. Otherwise, if the first and last name don't exist, insert a new document.

Currently, I'm only doing the import - and haven't yet built out the logic for this upsert piece.

```
app.post('/users/import', function(req, res) {
  let data = req.body;
  let dataArray = [];
  data.forEach(datum => {
    dataArray.push({
        first: datum.first,
        last: datum.last,
        age: datum.age
    })
})

User.insertMany(dataArray, answer => {
    console.log(`Data Inserted:`,answer)
})
```

`

And my User model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String,
  age: Number,
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: What versions of Mongoose and MongoDB are you using?

Comment: mongo - 3.2.9
mongoose - 4.6.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk upsert in MongoDB using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60331010/5318303)

Answer (score 70):

*(mongoose@4.9.1, mongodb@3.4.2)*

**TL;DR**

```js
await GasStation.collection.bulkWrite([ // <<==== use the model name
  {
    'updateOne': {
      'filter': { 'id': '<some id>' },
      'update': { '$set': { /* properties to update */ } },
      'upsert': true,  // <<==== upsert in every document
    }
  },
  /* other operations here... */
]);
```

**Long story:**

After struggling with [Mongoose API poor documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite), I solved the **bulk upsert** tweaking `updateOne:{}` operation in the `bulkWrite()` method.

A couple of undocumented things to consider:

```js
// suppose:
var GasStation = mongoose.model('gasstation', gasStationsSchema);
var bulkOps = [ ];

// for ( ... each gasStation to upsert ...) {
  let gasStation = { country:'a', localId:'b', xyz:'c' };
  // [populate gasStation as needed]
  // Each document should look like this: (note the 'upsert': true)
  let upsertDoc = {
    'updateOne': {
      'filter': { 'country': gasStation.country, 'localId': gasStation.localId },
      'update': gasStation,
      'upsert': true
  }};
  bulkOps.push(upsertDoc);
// end for loop

// now bulkWrite (note the use of 'Model.collection')
GasStation.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps)
  .then( bulkWriteOpResult => {
    console.log('BULK update OK');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(bulkWriteOpResult, null, 2));
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log('BULK update error');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  });
```

The two key things here are incomplete API documentation issues (at the time of writing, at least):

- `'upsert': true` **in each document**. This is not documented in Mongoose API (), which often refers to *node-mongodb-native* driver. Looking at [updateOne in this driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne), you could think to add `'options':{'upsert': true}`, but, no... that won't do. I also tried to add both cases to the `bulkWrite(,[options],)` argument, with no effect either.
- `GasStation.collection.bulkWrite()`. Although [Mongoose bulkWrite() method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) claims it should be called `Model.bulkWrite()` (in this case, `GasStation.bulkWrite()`), that will trigger `MongoError: Unknown modifier: $__`. So, `Model.collection.bulkWrite()` must be used.

Additionally, note:

- <s>You don't need to use the `$set` mongo operator in the `updateOne.update` field, since mongoose handles it in case of upsert (see [bulkWrite() comments in example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)).</s>
- Note that my unique index in the schema (needed for upsert to work properly) is defined as:

`gasStationsSchema.index({ country: 1, localId: 1 }, { unique: true });`

Hope it helps.

**==> EDIT: (Mongoose 5?)**

As noticed by @JustinSmith, the `$set` operator added by Mongoose doesn't seem to be working anymore. Maybe it's because of Mongoose 5?

In any case, using `$set` explicitly should do:

```
'update': { '$set': gasStation },
```

Comment: I guestt as of 2020, `Model.bulkWrite(bulkOps)` is the way to do it. `Model.collection.bulkWrite()` returns success but doesn't modify any data.

Comment: _id is always null when it creates a new document.

Comment: @ArpitYadav _id is not always null. Some applications set the _id on a new document before inserting. This can be useful if you have other documents that reference it and the _id is needed before updating db.

Comment: @maganap Thank you so much for the pointer to `Model.collection`. I spent hours trying to figure out why my `bulkWrite`s weren't working, and changing it to what you suggested solved my problem.

@YanekYuk in my case, using `Model.collection` returns success and updates the collection.

Answer (score 30):

Thank [@maganap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619537/maganap). I used [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952359/5318303) and reached below concise approach:

```js
await Model.bulkWrite(docs.map(doc => ({
    updateOne: {
        filter: {id: doc.id},
        update: doc,
        upsert: true,
    }
})))
```

---

Or more verbose:

```js
const bulkOps = docs.map(doc => ({
    updateOne: {
        filter: {id: doc.id},
        update: doc,
        upsert: true,
    }
}))

Model.bulkWrite(bulkOps)
        .then(console.log.bind(console, 'BULK update OK:', bulkWriteOpResult))
        .catch(console.error.bind(console, 'BULK update error:'))
```

Comment: Can you confirm `Model.bulkWrite()` works properly in newest mongoose versiones? Because I couldn't make it work on mongoose@4.9.1. I had to call `MyModel.collection.bulkWrite()` besides the `upsert: true` flag. That was a long time ago though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: should be `update: { $set: doc },` instead of `update: doc,`

Answer (score 6):

I have released a small plugin for Mongoose that exposes a static `upsertMany` method to perform bulk upsert operations with a promise interface. This should provide a very clean way of doing bulk upserts with Mongoose, while retaining schema validation etc:

```
MyModel.upsertMany(items, ['matchField', 'other.nestedMatchField']);
```

You can find this plugin on npm or Github:

https://github.com/meanie/mongoose-upsert-many https://www.npmjs.com/package/@meanie/mongoose-upsert-many

Answer (score 3):

I tried @magnap's solution above and found that it was overwriting the currently existing documents that I simply wanted to update. Rather than updating the fields I set in `updates.updateOne`, it was selecting the document and replacing all of its fields with the ones specified in `.update`.

I eventually had to use `$set` in my update method to resolve this. Here's what my controller ended up looking like:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

exports.bulkUpsert = (req, res, next) => {
     const { updates } = req.body;
     const bulkOps = updates.map(update => ({
         updateOne: {
             filter: { _id: ObjectId(update.id) },
             // Where field is the field you want to update
             update: { $set: { field: update.field } },
             upsert: true
          }
      }));
    // where Model is the name of your model
    return Model.collection
        .bulkWrite(bulkOps)
        .then(results => res.json(results))
        .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

This works with Mongoose 5.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array.map` instead use `for`

```
 const result = await Model.bulkWrite(
    documents.map(document => {

        document = {
          ...document, 
          ...{
            last_update: Date.now(),
            foo: 'bar'
          }
        }

        return {
          updateOne: {
            filter: { document_id: document.document_id }, //filter for each item
            update: {
              $set: document,//update whole document
              $inc: { version: 1 }//increase version + 1
            },
            upsert: true //upsert document
          }
        }

      }
    ));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285232/bulk-upsert-in-mongodb-using-mongoose/41907280#41907280) helps you out. It deals with bulk upsert for an ecommerce domain asynchronously

Answer (score -2):

Found the official solution on: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/

And Mongoose also supports same chain.

```
Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().update(<update>);
Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().updateOne(<update>);
Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().replaceOne(<replacement>);
```

Tested it works:

```
BulkWriteResult {
  result:
   { ok: 1,
     writeErrors: [],
     writeConcernErrors: [],
     insertedIds: [],
     nInserted: 0,
     nUpserted: 1,
     nMatched: 4186,
     nModified: 0,
     nRemoved: 0,
     upserted: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Comment: Error on Mongoose: upsert is not a function

Answer (score -4):

*check this i hope this will helpfull for you*
[link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285232/bulk-upsert-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

***I think you are looking for the***

[Bulk.find().upsert().update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert)

yo can use this

```
bulk = db.yourCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (<your for statement>) {
    bulk.find({ID: <your id>, HASH: <your hash>}).upsert().update({<your update fields>});
}
bulk.execute(<your callback>)
```

- If it finds one, it will update that document using {}
- Otherwise, it will create a new document

Comment: This us using the mongoDB client, not mongoose