# Multiple Document Upsert in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

Hello here is my problem,

```
var poolSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        "topic_id": {
            type: Number,
            default: null,
            required: true
        },
        "document_id": {
            type: String,
            default: null,
            required: true
        },
        "project":{
            type:String,
            default: false,
            required: true
        },
        "createddate":{
            type:Date,
            default : Date.now
        }
    }, { collection: "sorguHavuzu" });
```

i have an array of pool documents which each item has different field values such below :

```
var poolItems = [
                   {document_id :"FBIS3-50136" ,topic_id :"301" , project :"A1"},
                   {document_id :"LA040190-0178" ,topic_id :"302" , project :"A1"},
                   {document_id :"FT934-5418" ,topic_id :"303" , project :"A1"},
                   {document_id :"LA071090-0047" ,topic_id :"304" , project :"A1"}]
```

Here is my scheme :

I would like to upsert the items in the array by document_id field. So here is my update operation.

```
var query = {"document_id" : { $in:["FBIS3-50136","LA040190-0178","FT934-5418","LA071090-0047"]}};
Pools.collection.update(query, { $push : { "$ROOT" :  poolItems }  }, { upsert: true, multi : true}, callback);
```

Error: The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$ROOT\' in \'$ROOT\' is not valid for storage.

But on every attempt, i got different errors, is there a way to upsert items with mongoose update operation ?
Thanks

Comment: You want to upsert the items in `poolItems` into `pools` collection on the basis of `document_id`?

Comment: Yes, @TalhaAwan, this is correct

Comment: @TalhaAwan, any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to do a bulk upsert with Mongoose. What's the cleanest way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60330161/5318303)

Answer (score 3):

The bulk upsert is not really possible as mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286719/2327544), along with a possible solution.

However, you can consider simpler approach of using `upsert` operation for each `poolItems` with promise or some [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) method like [each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each). The below code should work:

```
var async = require('async');
var Pool = require('/path/to/pool.js');

var poolItems = [
{document_id :"FBIS3-50136" ,topic_id :"301" , project :"A1"},
{document_id :"LA040190-0178" ,topic_id :"302" , project :"A1"},
{document_id :"FT934-5418" ,topic_id :"303" , project :"A1"},
{document_id :"LA071090-0047" ,topic_id :"304" , project :"A1"}];

async.each(poolItems, function(poolItem, callback){
    Pool.findOneAndUpdate({document_id: poolItem.document_id}, poolItem, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
        if(err){
         return callback(err);
        }
        return callback();
    });
}, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("All pool items have been upserted!")
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought this way but concerning about performance the list is actually pretty big. Do you think it is still good approach?

Comment: I think it's a resonable approach. How big is the list?

Comment: At least 40 items

Comment: It's nothing. I thought of millions :) just go for it.

Comment: What is the changed approach? And how many documents is it considered too many to update via a for loop?