# Can mongoose batch update based on an array of objects that matches the collection?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project in Express/Node, and I am utilizing a MongoDB database that has a collection of Course documents that represent a course in my school system that changes in real-time. The Course documents in my database each look like this:

```
Course Document
    {
      courseID: Number,
      restrictions: String,
      status: String,
    }
```

My program has to check for changes in the school's course system, and update any changes that it sees and updates my private MongoDB database with the changes. To accomplish this, I currently have a script that looks at all the courses in the school system, and records them in an array of objects, with each object corresponding to a course.

```
var allCourses =     
    [
      {
        courseID: 123456,
        restrictions: "A and B",
        status: "OPEN"
      },
      {
        courseID: 678990,
        restrictions: "A",
        status: "FULL",
      }
    ]
```

The goal now is to be able to go through my database, and skip the documents that are the same as the corresponding javascript object in the array, and update those that are not.

Obviously, I could just iterate through my array with forEach, and update every single course by filtering by 'courseID' and updating both fields one document at a time, but I can foresee that this would take a large amount of time.

I was wondering if there was a batch update function, similar to the insertMany operation, that can take my array of objects and update my database documents that correspond to an object within the array?

Answer (score 0):

These are helpful links

[Trying to do a bulk upsert with Mongoose. What's the cleanest way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988848/trying-to-do-a-bulk-upsert-with-mongoose-whats-the-cleanest-way-to-do-this)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/