# Mongoose InsertOrReplace Many

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection of `Users` with unique property `UserName`. I need to `insert` in this collection array of Users. But if `UserNames` are `equal` I need to `replace` old document with the new one. (for each user)
Can be done this by one operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB update many if exist and create if not. Node API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218310/mongodb-update-many-if-exist-and-create-if-not-node-api)

Comment: Yeah they are doing the same thing but NOT with one operation. They essentially used a loop of queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk upsert in MongoDB using mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285232/bulk-upsert-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)