# give me an explanation of the code below, for bulk upsert in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm making a many insert in node using bulk upsert, and I get some code references from related links [bulk upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285232/bulk-upsert-in-mongodb-using-mongoose), and this is the code

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

 var sampleSchema  = new Schema({},{ "strict": false });

 var Sample = mongoose.model( "Sample", sampleSchema, "sample" );

 mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err,conn) { 

    var bulk = Sample.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    var counter = 0;

    // representing a long loop
    for ( var x = 0; x < 100000; x++ ) {

        bulk.find(/* some search */).upsert().updateOne(
            /* update conditions */
        });
        counter++;

        if ( counter % 1000 == 0 )
            bulk.execute(function(err,result) {             
                bulk = Sample.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
            });
    }

    if ( counter % 1000 != 0 )
        bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
           // maybe do something with result
        });

 });
```

and the code is right there is nothing wrong, but I still do not understand about some code below

```
if ( counter % 1000 == 0 )
            bulk.execute(function(err,result) {             
                bulk = Sample.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
            });
```

what is the purpose of this condition? `if ( counter % 1000 == 0 )` ?

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates whether `counter` is a multiple of 1,000.  More accurately, evaluates whether `counter / 1000` is equal to `0`.  See [Arithmetic Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Because this script is executing bulk operations, it is only executing batches of 1,000.  This condition enforces that.

Comment: @Omlegron If that solved your issue, would you mind voting and accepting the answer so that others may benefit from it as well.